# Plurality CS50 does not print multiple winners

Tags: c, cs50

Upon using check50, all the criteria are satisfied other than the one where it should print multiple winners in case of tie. The criterion that it should print all names when all candidates are tied is still somehow satisfied.
These are my results-
:

```
) plurality.c exists

:) plurality compiles

:) vote returns true when given name of first candidate

:) vote returns true when given name of middle candidate

:) vote returns true when given name of last candidate

:) vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate

:) vote produces correct counts when all votes are zero

:) vote produces correct counts after some have already voted

:) vote leaves vote counts unchanged when voting for invalid candidate

:) print_winner identifies Alice as winner of election

:) print_winner identifies Bob as winner of election

:) print_winner identifies Charlie as winner of election

** :( print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie

print_winner function did not print both winners of election **

:) print_winner prints all names when all candidates are tied
```

What should I fix in the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int p;
    for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < candidate_count; l++)
        {
            if (candidates[k].votes >= candidates[l].votes)
            {
                p = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                p = 0;
            }
        }
        if (p == 1)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[k].name);
        }
    }
    // TODO
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your code leaves `p` set to 1 if candidate `k` has at least as many votes as the last candidate tested in the loop using `l`. In each iteration, it sets `p` to 0 or 1, making no use of what was found in previous iterations.

Comment: Thanks i figured it out!